# Kivy + Python + Raspberry - How to implement countdown

Tags: python, kivy

I'm quite new to python programming and I'm currently building a photobooth using Kivy and Python.

In general it is working (I can press the button and it starts the function to take 3 pictures and updates the tumbnail on the screen) , but I'm not able to change the label text (actionLabel) to show a countdown before the takePhotos function starts.

```
import os, time, Image, sys, datetime, subprocess,glob


import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image as kivyImage
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 

#GPIO varialbes
#buttonPin = 23
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
GPIO_status = False

# Some variables
photoTitle = "My first Photobox!"
total_photos = 3 #Number of photos to be takes

#Function for photo taking
def takePhotos():

    #Take first picture - Folder for inbound pictures /home/pi/PB_Inbox/photobooth%H%M%S.jpg
    time.sleep(3)
    subprocess.call("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename /home/pi/PB_Inbox/photobooth%H%M%S.jpg", shell=True)
        #Take all other picture
        for x in range (0,total_photos-1):
            subprocess.call("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename /home/pi/PB_Inbox/photobooth%H%M%S.jpg", shell=True)
    #Process pictures
    subprocess.call("sudo sh /home/pi/Documents/Photo_Booth/Image_prep_3", shell=True)
    print('done')


class MyApp(App):
    # Display the latest thumbnail
    photo = kivyImage(source="/home/pi/PB_Thumb/Thumb.png")
    actionLabel = Label(text="Push the button", size_hint=(1, 0.2),color=[1,0,0,1],font_size='40sp')

    def build(self):
            # Set up the layout
            photobox = GridLayout(rows=3, spacing=10, padding=10)

            # Create the UI objects (and bind them to callbacks, if necessary)
            headerLabel = Label(text="The Greatest Photobox", size_hint=(1, 0.1),font_size='40sp') # Button: 20% width, 100% height

            # Add the UI elements to the layout
            photobox.add_widget(headerLabel)
            photobox.add_widget(self.photo)
            photobox.add_widget(self.actionLabel)

            # Periodically refresh the displayed photo using the callback function
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.3)

            return photobox      

    # Callback for thumbnail refresh and listening to GPIO for input
    def callback(self, instance):
        self.photo.reload()
        if self.readSensor() == False:
            pass
            #print('waiting')
        else:
            #provided as an argument
            takePhotos()

    #Read status of the sensor and return True if Buzzer has been pushed
    def readSensor(self):
        sensor = GPIO.input(23)
        if sensor == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Clock.create_trigger` to trigger the count down.
2. Remove the time.sleep(3) in function, takePhotos().
3. Use Clock.schedule_once to invoke function takePhotos() i.e. `Clock.schedule_once(takePhotos, 3)`
4. Separate the Kivy App into Python Script and kv file.

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

> In Kivy applications, you have to avoid long/infinite loops or sleeping.

## Example

### main.py

```
import os, time, sys, datetime, subprocess, glob

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# GPIO variables
# buttonPin = 23
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO_status = False

# Some variables
total_photos = 3    # Number of photos to be takes


# Function for photo taking
def takePhotos(dt):

    # Take 3 picture
    for x in range(total_photos):
        subprocess.call("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename /home/pi/PB_Inbox/photobooth%H%M%S.jpg", shell=True)

    # Process pictures
    subprocess.call("sudo sh /home/pi/Documents/Photo_Booth/Image_prep_3", shell=True)
    print('done')


class PhotoBox(BoxLayout):
    photo = ObjectProperty(None)
    action_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    count_down_trigger = ObjectProperty(None)
    count = NumericProperty(3)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PhotoBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Display the latest thumbnail
        self.photo.source = "/home/pi/PB_Thumb/Thumb.png"
        self.count_down_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.count_down, 1)

    def on_press_camera_button(self):
        self.count = 3
        self.count_down_trigger()

    def count_down(self, dt):
        self.action_button.text = str(self.count)
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count >= 0:
            self.count_down_trigger()
        else:
            self.action_button.text = "Say Cheese!"
            # Periodically refresh the displayed photo using the callback function
            # Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.3)    # infinite loop
            Clock.schedule_once(self.callback, 0.3)
            self.action_button.text = "Push the button"    # reset text

    # Callback for thumbnail refresh and listening to GPIO for input
    def callback(self, dt):
        self.photo.reload()
        if self.readSensor():
            # provided as an argument
            Clock.schedule_once(takePhotos, 3)  # call takePhotos method once after 3 seconds
        else:
            pass
            #print('waiting')

    # Read status of the sensor and return True if Buzzer has been pushed
    def readSensor(self):
        sensor = True   # GPIO.input(23)
        if sensor == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class MyApp(App):
    title = "My first Photobox!"

    def build(self):
        return PhotoBox()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

### my.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<PhotoBox>:
    photo: photo
    action_button:  action_button

    orientation:'vertical'
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10

    Label:
        text: "The Greatest Photobox"
        size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        font_size: '40sp'

    AsyncImage:
        id: photo

    Button:
        id: action_button
        text: "Push the button"
        size_hint: (1, 0.2)
        color: [1,0,0,1]
        font_size: '40sp'
        on_press: root.on_press_camera_button()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup] 
[image: Img02 - Count down]